# Vue.js orderBy decimal

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object which is a collection of data. on each item there is
- name
- date_created
- price

I can get the orderBy in Vue.js to work for name and date_created but it doesnt seem to work for price. The prices are stored in floats. 34.00, 12.00 0.00 etc etc..

Is there anything special i need to do here?

I've tried updating vue to the latest version but still no fix.

When I orderBy 'price' it does re-order the items but not in the correct way. It currently orders 4 items as outlined below;

```
0.00
57.00
7.00
88.40
```

reversing this order will do the above, but in reverse.

Thanks for any light someone can shed on this.

Comment: That sort ordering looks based on strings. Are your prices really stored as floats or are they actually strings?

Comment: prices were stored in floats. I've changed the database to store them in INT values which now fixed the orderBy issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably sorting as string, not number.

If you try sorting by decimals, it works fine (including some decimal formating):

```
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    items: [
      { price: 0.00 },
      { price: 57.00 },
      { price: 7.00 },
      { price: 88.40 }
    ]
  }
});

<ul id="demo">
  <li v-repeat="items | orderBy 'price'" >
   {{price.toFixed(2);}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/56LLvvw8/

Comment: Thanks for confirming it works. It turned out to be the fact I was storing the decimal in the DB as a 'DECIMAL' type. Once I changed this to 'FLOAT' it all seemed to work fine.